# Help in reverse engineering a boarding gate scanner's firmware

Tags: firmware

I'm working on a custom Access Control system for my local airport that will validate passengers' boarding passes and I've been given two **DESKO GRSK 502** scanners.

Unfortunately, there's absolutely no documentation available on them and the manufacturer is not willing to disclose any information on how the scanners operate even though they reached End of Service in 2020.

I managed to find a script that is used to update its firmware and it appears to contain what I've been looking for.

I am a complete newbie when it comes to reverse engineering, so the only things I've managed to get from the firmware are some random command strings. Unfortunately, however, the scanner always returns a 'Negative Acknowledge' response, so I'm guessing it expects some initialization command before accepting any others.

Here is the firmware itself: https://pastebin.com/UDgne3Q8
I used Hex2Bin to convert the firmware file to a .bin file and the loaded it up on IDA Pro. Upon Googling, I came across [this blog post](https://revengrazer.blogspot.com/2013/06/firmware-part-3-setting-up-ida-pro.html) which mentions that IDA Pro should be provided with the processor's ROM start address in order to decompile it properly.

Here's the inside of the scanner:

[image]

I assumed that the processors is 'P80C5521BA', but there's no information on NXP's website on its ROM start address.

I would appreciate any help I can get in extracting any information from that firmware file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The CPU in the `P80C552` microcontroller is a `80C51`.
After reset, this begins execution at address `0x0000`.

A quick inspection of your firmware hex file confirms this.

This is -

```
:03000000020403F4

=>
0000:  020403    LJMP $0403  // long jump to address `0x0403`
```

If we follow this -

```
:10040000320178C2AFC2977581AD90FFD043820FA1

=>

0403:  C2AF      CLR IE.7 // disable all interrupts
....
```

After disabling interrupts, the code continues as typical reset code, setting the stack pointer, data pointer etc.

This confirms that address `0000` is a plausible start address for your firmware.

However, to actually use it in IDA you need to be aware that the 8051 has a Harvard architecture. Please look at the related question & answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22168/loading-8051-binary-to-ida-with-romexternal-ram-configuration) for details.